# return to newly custom object created page

Tags: apex, visualforce, custom, object

I am creating a new object with an apex class and a controller.
My goal is when I call my method that create a new instance of that custom object, to redirect me to the page where the new object is.

For now I am doing :

```
 PageReference test789456 = new PageReference('/' +parent);
 return test789456;
```

where parent is my customobject id.

Is there any better way ? Meaning I don't like absolute path

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can actually return like below:

```
public static String fetchPagereference() {
    Pagereference pr = new ApexPages.StandardController(new Account(Id=parent)).view();
    return pr.getUrl();
}
```